# Possible select column name with filter

Tags: php, mysql

I try to filter my column name when `SELECT` statement and my query like below :

```
$query = "select p.id, p.name from `person` p";
```

Column 'name' data something like below :

Angelina Jolie | Brad Pitt | David Beckham ....

**Filter :**

When select column name (p.name) i just want select 'name' string then remove all string after space. Mean when i select the column i just select name Angelina, Brad, David ...

**i know we can do this using implode but i want filter inside query line .*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this::

```
select substring_index(p.name,' ',1) as name, p.id from person p
```

Comment: thanks .. and this function substring_index we can do in where statement also i guess ..

Comment: Yes you can use that in where too, or you can use the alias name that is "name" in the where clasue, this will be much more efficient..:-)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select p.id, left(p.name,locate(' ',p.name)-1) from `person` p
```

#### [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/4054)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.name , ' ', 1) `name`  FROM `person` p;
```

Comment: Bhai hum dono ka soch kitna milta hai, mera answer dekhna..:-)